# Toggle/Show one defined DIV with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, toggle

I have a fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/vSs4f/

I want to show the `div.sub-menu` with a simple click on `a.haschildren`. If the body loads the `div.sub-menu` should be closed. If I click a second time on `a.haschildren` the `div.sub-menu` should be close.

I have sampled so many things but I think the problems are the lot of DIV's. One idea is in the fiddle.

```
$(function()   {
    $("a.haschildren").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('div.sub-menu:visible').hide();
        $(this).next('div.sub-menu').show();
    });
});
```

I really hope you can help me, thanks!

Comment: Generally, you should include at least part of the markup/script code you're stuck on inside your question; jsFiddle isn't guaranteed to always be there, so if someone finds this question later, having some of the code helps keep the context intact (hence the edit by Mr. Alien).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(function()   {
    $("a.haschildren").click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        var item = $(this).closest('div.haschildren').next().next('div.sub-menu').toggle();
        $('div.sub-menu:visible').not(item).hide();
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kj2bp/)

Comment: The solution is `.next().next('...')` ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:-

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jwBke/)

```
 $(function () {
    $("a.haschildren").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var subMenu = $(this).closest('div.haschildren').nextUntil('.sub-menu').next().toggle();
        $('div.sub-menu:visible').not(subMenu).hide();
      
    });
});
```

Using `.nextUntil` to reach a point till the `.sub-menu`, incase any other siblings come in between this will still work.

Comment: Thanks for the `.nextUntil`-Tip

Answer (score 2):

Personally there are MANY things I would have changed about the structure of your DOM. I am a strong believer that you should base your javascript structure around a well structured DOM, so the traversal is very easy and intuitive. That being said, I'm going to be slightly daring by submitting my fiddle, in the hope that if nothing else, you can look at it and gain a little insight on how to take advantage of a few DOM quirks to make your javascript a bit more intuitive and elegant.

http://jsfiddle.net/vSs4f/6/

```
$(function()   {
    $('#menu > div.item')
        .find('a').click(function() {
            var submenu_index = $(this).parents('.item:first').find('.sub-menu').toggle().index('.sub-menu');

            // This chunk can disappear if you're not interested in hiding all of the other sub-menus
            $('.sub-menu').filter(function(index) {
                if(index != submenu_index)
                    return true;
            }).hide();
        }).end()
        .find('div:first').after('<div class="trenner"></div>');
});
```

Comment: It's right. The structure of this snippet is very bad, but for this layout, it's usefull :-)

Answer (score 1):

just use `toggle()`

```
$('div.sub-menu').toggle();
```

Answer (score 1):

Ironically enough, the method you're looking for is .toggle();

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: toggle() will work ALOT better if the layout was hierarchical

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```
$(function()   {
    $("div.haschildren").click(function() {
        if($(this).next().next('div.sub-menu').is(":hidden")){
            $('div.sub-menu:visible').hide();
            $(this).next().next('div.sub-menu').show();
        }else{
            $(this).next().next('div.sub-menu').hide();
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```