# Navbar collapsing without Bootstrap

Tags: html, css

Hi I was trying to get my navigation bar to collapse on smaller screen size I am trying to do this without bootstrap any suggestions?

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <!-- CSS STYLESHEET -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat|Black+Ops+One|Luckiest+Guy|Montez|Courgette|Slackey|Fontdiner+Swanky|Permanent+Marker|Aclonica|Lobster" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!-- JavaScript's -->
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    // note that this doens't call hide   
    $('#loading').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow');
});
</script>
<body>
<div id="loading">
<div id="loading-center">
<div id="loading-center-absolute">
<div id="object"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Loading Section Ends -->
<div class="header">
<nav class="nav_first">
            <img class="nike" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/nikeinc/assets/7366/Nike_Swoosh_Logo_White_original.jpg?1328660973">

  <ul>
    <li class="wiggle" class="wiggle" class="wiggle" class="wiggle"><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
    <li class="wiggle" class="wiggle" class="wiggle"><a href="about.php">About Us</a></li> 
    <li class="wiggle" class="wiggle"><a href="/shop">Shop</a></li> 
    <li class="wiggle"><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div>
        <h1 id="nike_text">Nike</h1>
    </div>  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    font-size:14px;
    margin:0;
    background-color:black;
}
#loading {
    display:none;
    background-color: #bd4932;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-top: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}
#loading-center{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
#loading-center-absolute {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-top: -100px;
    margin-left: -100px;
}
#object{
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    -webkit-animation: animate 1s infinite ease-in-out;
    animation: animate 1s infinite ease-in-out;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: 60px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate {
  0% { -webkit-transform: perspective(160px); }
  50% { -webkit-transform: perspective(160px) rotateY(-180deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: perspective(160px) rotateY(-180deg) rotateX(-180deg); }
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% { 
    transform: perspective(160px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: perspective(160px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg); 
  } 50% { 
    transform: perspective(160px) rotateX(-180deg) rotateY(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: perspective(160px) rotateX(-180deg) rotateY(0deg) ;
  } 100% { 
    transform: perspective(160px) rotateX(-180deg) rotateY(-180deg);
    -webkit-transform: perspective(160px) rotateX(-180deg) rotateY(-180deg);
  }
}
/* SASU - Navigation Bar */
.nav_first{
    overflow:none;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-align:center;
}
.nav_first li{
    display:inline;
}
.nav_first a{
    margin-top:25px;
    font-size: 30px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-weight:900;
    margin-left:40px;
    margin-right:40px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    text-decoration: none;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:10px;
}
.nav_first a:hover {
    color:white;
    font-size:35px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes wiggle {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform:rotate(4deg);
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform:rotate(-4deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform:rotate(4deg);
    }
}

.wiggle:hover {
    -webkit-animation: wiggle 0.5s infinite;
}
.active {background-color:orangered;}
img{
    float:left;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0 auto;
}
/* Middle Section */
.nike {
    display: block;
    margin:auto;
    height:115px;
}
#nike_text {
    font-family:'Montez';
    font-size:80px;
    text-align: center;
    color:white;
    margin:auto;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: Your JsBin contains way too much code. Please extract the essential part and include it directly here in your question.

Comment: Also, I don't see a single line of media queries in your css. What did you try do far?

Comment: @Michal Szyndel I didn't use media queries here because it's useless I'm not going to be making to smaller etc I need it to collapse and have button

Comment: And how are you going to do that?

Comment: Hey @Michal Szyndel I meant I don't use it for that reason

Comment: "on smaller screen size" requires either media queries or JavaScript. The former is almost always preferred.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Toggle/Show one defined DIV with JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16557129/toggle-show-one-defined-div-with-js)